# Animating groups of paths Raphael

Tags: animation, raphael

I'm new to Raphael and coding in general, so please bear with me as I lumber through this question.  I am having trouble animating groups of paths in Raphael.  My desired effect is a set of paths running individual animations while moving around the paper in unison.  Here is an example:

```
path1 = paper.path("path string").attr({fill: "#fff", stroke: "#000"});
path2 = paper.path("path string").attr({fill: "#fff", stroke: "#000"});
path3 = paper.path("path string").attr({fill: "#fff", stroke: "#000"});
pathSet = paper.set(path1, path2, path3);
pathSet.animate({transform: "t500,500"}, 1000);

path1.mouseover(function(){path1.animate({transform: "s1.6,r10"}, 1000)});
path2.mouseover(function(){path2.animate({transform: "s1.6,r10"}, 1000)});
path3.mouseover(function(){path3.animate({transform: "s1.6,r10"}, 1000)});
```

In the above example, the pathSet will animate just like it should, but when I mouse over the individual paths, they don't just scale and rotate in place, but translate back to their original coordinates (where they were prior to the pathSet animation).  I read in the docs about the relative "t,r,s" and absolute "T,R,S" parameters for transformations and thought that was it, but they don't seem to make a difference.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You've hit upon what I take to be one of Raphael's biggest weaknesses: transform animations are difficult to combine gracefully!

This won't be a perfect solution, but you can always use the mouseover/mouseout handlers to append/counter the changes you want.  For instance:

```
path1.mouseover(function(){path1.animate({transform: "...s1.5,r10"}, 1000)});
path2.mouseover(function(){path2.animate({transform: "...s1.5,r10"}, 1000)});
path3.mouseover(function(){path3.animate({transform: "...s1.5,r10"}, 1000)});

path1.mouseout(function(){path1.animate({transform: "...s0.66,r-10"}, 1000)});
path2.mouseout(function(){path2.animate({transform: "...s0.66,r-10"}, 1000)});
path3.mouseout(function(){path3.animate({transform: "...s0.66,r-10"}, 1000)});
```

The append/counter approach will work fine so long as you don't need a stateful reaction from any given element.  Once that happens, it seems to me to make more sense to create a wrapper class for a type of object that will keep track of where it should be, adjusting the absolute transform as necessary.  But you may not need such a thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Zero.  I did consider using mouseout, but I need the paths to do an animation then too.  I was really hoping I was missing something, but from what you're saying, it looks like this is an inherent issue.  Has anyone written any kind of plugin or extension that addresses this?  Thanks!

Comment: So I started looking into writing a wrapper for Element to get/set absolute position, and ran into another issue.  Setting the x or y attr on a path has no effect.  You can get back what you set with attr(), but the path does not move.  What gives?

Comment: That's another pet peeve of mine.  The "absolute" positioning for a path is encoding in the path itself, which is exactly why translation is so important (and so frustratingly limited).  Believe me, I feel your pain.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're talkig about.  The first set of coordinates in the SVG path string (starting with M) specifies a "moveTo" location for the first point in the path.  So I'm guessing the solution will involve retreiving the path string, parsing out the "M
" coordinates, performing calculations on them, and then re-drawing the path.  This seems like it would have a very negative impact on performance.Correct my thinking here, if I'm off base.  Thanks!

Comment: An alternate solution I was thinking of was to group elements inside separate paper instances, putting the papers in divs, and animating the divs with jQuery.  Cumbersome, but it would work...and avoid re-drawing paths.  Would that be better for performance?

Comment: Don't forget there's a helper function for parsing path strings -- but it could still damage performance if you're doing it a lot (http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.parsePathString).  I'd be very curious to see how a jQuery + Raphael animation approach pans out...  my guess is it will suffer performance issues as well.

Comment: Well, animating with jQuerry didn't work.  When I wrap the paper script in a div tag, it doesn't treat the div as a parent.  Coordinates are absolute.  So when I animate the div, nothing happens to the paper.  Thanks for the path parsing tip, will try that next.